# How this leaflet code loading images

Tags: leaflet

code taken from this url http://thematicmapping.org/playground/zoomify/example.html

```
var map = L.map('photo').setView(new L.LatLng(0,0), 0);

L.tileLayer.zoomify('http://thematicmapping.org/playground/zoomify/books/', {
    width: 5472,
    height: 3648,
    tolerance: 0.8,
    attribution: 'Photo: Bjørn Sandvik'
}).addTo(map);
```

if anyone goto url which i pasted at top and check the source then must notice no z,y or x has been mention in code but their code working file and loading tiles. how the code is working ?

anyone can see the code and tell me how the code loading tiles without z,y and x ?

please share the knowledge. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "magic" is coded within [Leaflet.Zoomify plugin](https://github.com/turban/Leaflet.Zoomify) ([documentation](http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/06/showing-zoomify-images-with-leaflet.html)).

The `z`, `x`and `y` values are appended to the URL path by the plugin, which assumes that the tiles structure follows [Zoomify](http://www.zoomify.com) convention (hence the name of the plugin).